# "run the wickets of"

Tags: vocabulary

I was watching a documentary recently and I couldn't understand something:

"At this point, we were running the wickets of the investigation."

What does "to run the wickets of" mean?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To **run the wickets** is apparently a term from the game of croquet, and not as one might expect cricket. (**Wicket** is a North American term for a croquet hoop - [OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/wicket))

It means to complete the game in one turn. The following is a piece of an article in [Country Roads](http://www.countryroadsmagazine.com/getaways/outdoor-adventures/the-red-stick-croquet-club) magazine:

> Cochran said [ . . . ]
>
> “If you’re really good at it, you can run the wickets in a single turn
>   just like you run the table in pool.”

So, the metaphorical usage (rare on the internet) means to make swift progress towards your goal.

Comment: The edit certainly improves the answer. And mikeagg couldn't really add a substantially different (correct) answer. I usually think that site politics should defer to quality (though that soon becomes a minefield).

Answer (score 4):

It's not correct. Read the rules of сroquet. You have to pass all the wickets to win. So idiomatically, it means more "do something step by step", not swift progress.

*You still have to run the wickets.*

Comment: Croquet, Anna, not crocket. But I think you’re right.  Doing things in order, step by step.

Comment: It would help to know what was happening in the original program - presumably someone who watched it would know if they were fast or slow.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the misspelling.

Comment: In that example said "run the wickets in a single turn"  - when you have this specification "in a single turn", it's already clear, that "run the wickets" itself not smth fast, but smth huge and slow. It's like "a mile at one jump".